# Why is my code not print the data fields of document in my subcollection in Flutter and Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
final CollectionReference wLCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('').collection('Weightlifting');
```

What do I put inside the parenthesis for .doc() so that I can access and print out all the fields of all the documents inside my subcollection?

This is the rest of my code:

```
List<WeightliftingLogs?> _WLlistFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
  return WeightliftingLogs(
      date: doc.get('date') ?? Timestamp.now(),
      deadLiftWeight: doc.get('deadLiftWeight') ?? 0,
    deadLiftReps: doc.get('deadLiftReps') ?? 0,
    backSquatWeight: doc.get('backSquatWeight') ?? 0,
    backSquatReps: doc.get('backSquatReps') ?? 0,
    hipThrustWeight: doc.get('hipThrustWeight') ?? 0,
    hipThrustReps: doc.get('hipThrustReps') ?? 0,
    legPressWeight: doc.get('legPressWeight') ?? 0,
    legPressReps: doc.get('legPressReps') ?? 0,
    benchPressWeight: doc.get('benchPressWeight') ?? 0,
    benchPressReps: doc.get('benchPressReps') ?? 0,
    lateralPulldownWeight: doc.get('lateralPulldownWeight') ?? 0,
    lateralPulldownReps: doc.get('lateralPulldownReps') ?? 0,
    bicepCurlWeight: doc.get('bicepCurlWeight') ?? 0,
    bicepCurlReps: doc.get('bicepCurlReps') ?? 0,
    tricepExtensionWeight: doc.get('tricepExtensionWeight') ?? 0,
    tricepExtensionReps: doc.get('tricepExtensionReps') ?? 0

  );

}).toList();
}
  Stream<List<WeightliftingLogs?>> get WLlogs {
return wLCollection.snapshots().map(_WLlistFromSnapshot);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query across all collections named `Weightlifting` you'll need to [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('Weightlifting')
```